# How to send a updated values in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I need to send all urls including last updated values from mongodb.

but i only get previous updated values.Can any body tell the me solution .

```
new_add_schema.findOneAndUpdate(
{ 
    user_id: req.body.user_id 
},
{ 
   $push: 
   { 
      filename: 
      {
          url:img_filename 
       } 
   }
},
function(err, doc) {
     console.log(doc)
});
```

Comment: You can take the last updated one with the result concated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In mongoose you can pass `options` as the third argument for this method. If you pass `new: true` in options then Mongo will return the updated document. It is `false` by default.

So query like this -

```
new_add_schema.findOneAndUpdate(
{ 
user_id: req.body.user_id 
},
{ 
   $push: 
   { 
      filename: 
      {
          url:img_filename 
      } 
   }
},
{new: true}, // notice this options argument
function(err, doc) {
 console.log(doc)
});
```

You can see the documentation [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate).

Comment: yes its working fine , thanks for your fast response